# How to format the Input type date "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im tring to format the date like dd/mm/yyyy, I`ve tried dateFormat, format but not succeed, someone could help me? thanks

```
(import { Input } from 'antd';)           

 <Input onChange={event => {
                    this.setState({ validade: event.target.value });
                  }}
              type="date"
              dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"
            />
```

Comment: I don't think `dateFormat` is a valid prop for `Input`. Did you mean to use `DatePicker`?

Comment: you may want a date picker https://ant.design/components/date-picker/,  not sure about react native

Comment: Consider *this* for **react-native**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Comment: I used the DatePicker native, it works, thanks !!

Comment: You can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker